# Normalization of $A[X,\sqrt{aX}]$, where $A$ is a DVR.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

> Let $A$ be a discrete valuation ring, and let $a\in A$ be a non-zero element. Compute the integral closure of $B:=A[X,\sqrt{aX}]$.

We assume the fact that $B$ is integrally closed if and only if $v(a)\le 1$. (Here $v$ denotes the valuation of $A$.)

So suppose that $v(a)=n$, with $n\ge 2$. Then, denoted the maximal ideal of $A$ as $(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in A$ (and $v(\alpha)=1$), we have that $a=u\alpha^n$, where $u\in A$ is a unit.

If $n=2m$ is even, $B=A[X,\alpha^m\sqrt{uX}]$. Notice that $B\subsetneq A[X,\sqrt{uX}]$, and this extension is clearly integral; moreover, $A[X,\sqrt{uX}]$ is integrally closed (by the initial assumption plus the fact that $v(u)=0$).

If $n=2m+1$ is odd, $B=A[X,\alpha^m\sqrt{u\alpha X}]$. Here $B\subsetneq A[X,\sqrt{u\alpha X}]$, that is again an integral extension; plus, $A[X,\sqrt{u\alpha X}]$ is integrally closed because $v(u\alpha)=1$.

Thus I would say that the integral closure of $B$ is $A[X,\sqrt{u X}]$ when $v(a)$ is even and $\ge 2$, and it is $A[X,\sqrt{u\alpha X}]$ when $v(a)$ is odd and $\ge 2$. (If $v(a)\le 1$ we already knew that the integral closure is $B$ itself.)

Do you think it is a valid argument? Or have I committed any mistake? Thank you

Comment: You have to show that $B$ and its integrally closed ring extensions which you mentioned have the same field of fractions. (Otherwise you are in trouble, as the following general example shows: $k[x^2]\subset k[x]$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to show something more: the field of fractions of $B$ equals the field of fractions of $A[X,\sqrt{uX}]$ for $n=2m$, and similarly for $n$ odd.

But this is easy enough since $\sqrt{uX}=\frac{\alpha^m\sqrt{uX}}{\alpha^m}\in Q(B)$. ($Q(B)$ denotes the field of fractions of $B$.)

Comment: Indeed I forgot to check it; it should follow, wether $n$ is odd or even, from $\alpha^m\in Q(B)$